# Html/Css Top Bar: Align two contents in diffrent positions of top bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to create a top bar with the following structure

---

```
                               Tel:4949494949                    social media icons
```

---

In the middle I'm trying to have contact info and at almost in right my social media icons.

I'm not able to place social media in right. CSS always gets them to the middle, next to contact info.
What is wrong?

```css
#tpbr_box .a {
  width: 10%;
  height: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 20px!important;
}

#tpbr_box .social2 {
  float: right;
}

#tpbr_box {
  font-size: 20px!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <i class="fa fa-home"></i> |
  <a style="color:white;" href="tel:54543">354353535</a>

</div>
<div class="social2">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and the snippet within it, to include the `#tpbr_box` element in the HTML box. This will produce a [mre], which will help answerers.

Comment: Trying to achieve this using text-align and float is really rather old-school, you should look into more contemporary layout models, such as flexbox.

Comment: `#tpbr_box .a` looks like an error, it should be `#tpbr_box a`

Comment: Do you need it like this? https://prnt.sc/10q0b39

Comment: @mohammedalshobaki almost like this. but the contact info in the middle, and the social almost in the right side

Comment: Like this:
 https://prnt.sc/10q0f6e

Comment: @mohammedalshobaki yes, this is perfect. but social media little more left

Comment: of course i will!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirements, Info to the middle, and social to the right side!

Try this:

```
<!-- Html code --> 
  <div class="top_nav">
    <div class="info">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i> |
     <a style="color:whites;" href="tel:54543">354353535</a>
    </div>
     <div class="social2">
         <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
         <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
         <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
         <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
     </div>
 </div>
```

And here is the CSS style:

```
 #tpbr_box .a {
      width: 10%;
      height: 20%;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline;
      font-size: 20px!important;
  }
  #tpbr_box .social2{
      float:right;
 }

  #tpbr_box  {
          font-size: 20px!important;
  }
 .top_nav{
        display: flex;
  }
  .top_nav    .social2  {
    position: absolute;
    right: 14px;
  }
  .info{
        margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

Make sure add parent div with "**top_nav**" class to control the style.

Comment: dont know if thanks is enough. Thank you very much!. Also if i want to add some space between social i have to add ```margin-right```?

Comment: You're most welcome! between social icons?  just add padding :
  .social2 a{
        padding-left: 4px;
      }
and increase it as you like! @yakel

Answer (score 1):

I switched out the div classes because when you use a new one, it writes itt in a new line. I fixed this by using a a-class instead of a div, still giving an class to each one. The reason why I used width and margin-left with percents is no matter the length, the html will adjust(ex. you resize the window, it resizes with it).

```css
.topbar {
  width: 100%
}

.info {
  margin-left: 45%
}

.social2 {
  margin-left: 55%
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <a class='center'>
   <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
   <a href="tel:54543">354353535</a>
  </a>
  <a class='social2'>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook">f</a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter">t</a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram">i</a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube">y</a>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem comes from the fact that you put a `text-align: center;` on your links. Putting a `text-align: center;`  on the tags a, all your links present on your page will go to the middle.